# Can Telegraf combine/add value of metrics that are per-node, say for a cluster?

Tags: time-series, influxdb, telegraf

Let's say I have some software running on a VM that is emitting two metrics that are fed through Telegraf to be written into InfluxDB. Let's say the metric are no. successfully handled HTTP requests (S), and no. of failed HTTP requests (F), on that VM. However, I might configure three such VMs each emitting those 2 metrics.

Now, if I would like to have a computed metric which is the sum of S from each VM, and sum of F from each VM, and store as new metrics, at various instants of time. Is this something that can be achieved using Telegraf ? Or is there a better, more efficient, more elegant way ?

Kindly note that my knowledge of Telegraf and InfluxDB are theoretical, as I've recently started reading up about them, so I have not actually tried any of the above, yet.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do this in telegraf, but I am able to mathematically manipulate my metrics at the metrics's destination (Datadog, and it should also be possible in Prometheus). I think it makes more sense to do this at the destination. You dont want to start editing logic in your telegraf clients once they are deployed - its a pain.

Comment: Thanks @FuzzyAmi. Isn't Prometheus an alternative to InfluxDB, i.e. yet another timeseries DB ? I suppose, you meant that instead of having this login in Telegraf, instead have it in whatever timeseries DB being used, right ?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I meant by 'destination'. InfluxDb, Prometheus, DataDog are all examples for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something `telegraf` would be responsible for.

With Influx 1.x, you'd use a TICKScript or Continuous Queries to calculate the sum and inject the new sampled value.

Roughly, this would look like:

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY "sum_sample_daily" ON "database"
BEGIN
  SELECT sum("*") INTO "daily_measurement" FROM "measurement" GROUP BY time(1d)
END
```

[CQ docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/continuous_queries/)